# How to restrict the number of launching an Android application in the day

Tags: java, android

I just wanna know how to let users for **maximum two times a day** on my application. That means that the app will block the users if they are going to enter for a third time in a day.

Comment: Just do as you would do in real life: keep a list of users, and count the times they come to visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to solve your purpose with below steps:

1. create a sharedPreference which would store the count of the app launches.
2. as soon as you launch the app (your MainActivity), in OnCreate() of the activity get values from the preference and check if its already equal to predefined MAX_USES_COUNT ( in your case 2).
3. if its less than predefined MAX_USES_COUNT then increment it by one and save the modified value in sharedPref.
4. if the value is already >= MAX_USES_COUNT then simply call finish within onCreate().

To clear the preferences on date change you can you two approaches:

1. use a broadcast receiver registered with action `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED`. reff [this document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED) . and set the pref count to zero.
2. or you can use one more item in preference to store the date on which pref is edited. so when you launch your activity you check the count as well as compare the system date with the stored date from pref.

I hope this will solve your purpose.

Comment: That's ok then how will you clear that sharedPreferences after a day ? as you said your app tends to be used only 2 times, not two times a day.

Comment: i edited my answer for explaining that part. please check it.

Comment: I am not OP to accept your answer. Have a look. I am just supporter.

Comment: Wow! Thank's for your fast reply! It would be awesome if you would show me how the Code, that stores the app launches in  the sharedPreference looks like.

Comment: @MagicKnight : that will be off-topic to write complete code here as per community trends. try implementing yourself. if you get any doubt in that you can ask it again. in the main time you can vote-up or accept the answer if you find it useful. :)

Comment: Yah your right. But how do I reset my SharedPreference after 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem. What if user clear app data during the day? In this moment sharedpreferences will disappear. Try to write count of application launches on SD card(or emulated SD card) hidden.

Comment: if you consider problem of clear-data, then you must consider the problem of SDcard unmounting and file deletion by user.
Actually SDCard data is more prone to user interference than app-memory (like database or preference).